# when open an android project on eclipse i got some errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I update my os to win 8.1.Then i installed adt bundle.When i create a project on eclipse it creates project without any activity.I mean the src file is empty and also there is no xml file like main_activity.xml.Btw i can debug my old applications that i developed on win7.
Then i update my sdk.This time it creates activities but as an actionBarActivity.I mean MainActivity extedns ActionBarActivity.Also when the project created on folder appcompatv_7 is automatically created on my workspace.Then i code something it doesnt work on my phone but i know the code is totaly true.Help me please. 
I removed the adt and reinstall it.
I check the updates.Eclipse didnt found any update.
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

My sdk manage looks like
[image]

Comment: This question in its current form does not give me enough information to understand your problem. To me it reads like "I changed the breaks on my car. Then I replaced the front tires. The car wont start but I know it is not broken". You need to be much, much more specific in describing your problem (which is not the same as just listing everything you have done).

Comment: i added some screen shots to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make your own activity by going into: src > com.example.projectName. Right click this, and create a new class. Make that class extend Activity.

If you want Eclipse to make your main_activity for you, then you probably did not "check" one of the checkboxes to make a new activity along with your new android application project. To do this, please do the following:

```
1. File > new > android project
2. A new window should appear. Name your android application as usual, and click next.
3. This step is important. You must check the "Create Activity" checkbox. You probably did not do this the first time, which was why
you had an empty android application project.
4. Click next until you see the "Create Activity" option. You can choose from either a blank activity, Fullscreen activity, or
Master/detail flow. Click the "blank activity" in order to get a
normal activity (and when I say normal activity, I mean the
MainActivity.java and the main_activity.xml)
```

Also, whenever you make a new activity in a pre-existing project, be sure to carefully read all the options. Right click your package in the src folder, press new > android activity, and carefully read all the options.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: i do the steps that you said.I checked the Create activity checkbox.The problem is not resolved.Src file is still empty.When i try to add activity to src eclipse says The refactoring does not change any source code.